# Parenthesis in currying and type declaration

Tags: functional-programming, currying, type-declaration

I'm having a hard time understanding notation used for currying. Maybe it means I have a deeper confusion regarding the subject but I don't think so.

I understand how something like...

`add (x,y) = x + y` can have a type `(int, int) -> int`.

It also makes sense the curried form would look like this:

`add x y = x + y` with type `int -> int -> int`, aka type `int -> (int-> int)`.

I would like to know what the parenthesis mean in that last example. Is the first `int` `x`, the second `int` `y`, and the last `int` the output? What would a function like this look like?

`(int -> int) -> int`

I know something isn't clicking and it's very frustrating.

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that (int, int) is a tuple. Hope it helps you to click!

Comment: @snf Right, so the input is on the left and the output is on the right?

Comment: `add x y = x y` is `x:int -> y:int -> res:int` if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Ok. So what's an example of `(int -> int) -> int`?

Comment: Let's say there is a function apply (that is for ints): `let apply f x = f x`, this needs a function f:(int -> int), an x:int and returns an int so the description of the function is `(int -> int) -> int -> int`, then any f that satisfies (int -> int) can be passed as argument, for example a function `let inc x = x + 1`. I would suggest playing with an interpreter like the one that includes haskell or ocaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types of the form `a -> b` really just mean

> function taking a value of type `a` and returning a value of type `b`

And from there on it's just repeated application for larger (multiple arrows) types, much like `1 + 2 + 3 + 4` isn't all that different from `1 + 2`.
One potential stumbling stone is that either of these values can be a function itself. Your interpretation of the curried type is correct, but note that `add x` is a valid expression on its own, and gives another function (one which only needs one argument before returning an `int`).

As for the second type: Just like `int -> (int -> int)` is the type

> take an `int` and return a function `int -> int`"

the type `(int -> int) -> int` means

> take a function `int -> int` and return an `int`

It's a higher-order function, a function which accepts a function as argument.
One not-entirely-useless example would be the function `sum0To100 f = sum (map f [0 .. 100])` (or equivalent functions for any other range). For example, `sum0To100 fib` is the sum of the first 100 Fibonacci numbers.